# Gutenprint possible problem

Tags: printing, canon

Could not print a label directly from EBAY. operated print button but print page kept timing out.  Printed it to my email account and could print it from there. Can print other files OK. In print queue was ref to this gulten thing. I did a system update but this didn't do the trick. Is this gluten thing the problem is it not part of the standard package? or do I have to add separately? Printer is Canon MX470

cheers Omhie

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu studio
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco

Browers is Chromium

Also had trouble with Simple scan but looks like a restart fixed it not checked again.

Comment: Please click [edit] and put the version number of Ubuntu you use in your question. Also please tell us which web browser you use to access eBay.  Please don't click Add Comment; use [Edit] instead.